# New query within MySql query based on an initial query result

Tags: php, mysql, select, inner-join, concat-ws

I'm trying to get the contact info from one table ("SP_Cont") and then, based on the county code (CID), get the actual county name ("CTitle") from the "Counties" table.

```
SELECT 
CONCAT_WS(', ',NULLIF(SP_Cont.Address1, ''),NULLIF(SP_Cont.Address2, ''),NULLIF(SP_Cont.Address3, ''),NULLIF(SP_Cont.Address4, ''),NULLIF(SP_Cont.Address5, ''),NULLIF(SP_Cont.City, ''),NULLIF(Postcode, '')) AS Address, SP_Cont.CID, SP_Cont.RevTot,
Counties.CTitle
FROM 
  SP_Cont
INNER JOIN
  Counties
ON
  Counties.CID=SP_Cont.CID
WHERE
  SP_Cont.SPCode = "26"
```

What I want to achieve is an address that looks like this...

**Address1, Address2, Address3, City, County, Postcode.**

I know the above won't do that, but at least I won't have to run another query within the PHP page to add the county as I currently do:

```
if (!empty($BAPrint['CID'])) {
 $CQuery = mysql_query ("SELECT CTitle FROM Counties USE INDEX (CIDT) WHERE CID = ".$BAPrint['CID']);
  $CPrint = mysql_fetch_array ($CQuery);
  $Address .= ", ".$CPrint['CTitle'];
}
```

So it will look like this:

**Address1, Address2, Address3, City, Postcode, County.**

Is there a way to get the desired address format of

**Address1, Address2, Address3, City, County, Postcode.**?

The other issue is if the SP_Cont does not contain an CID code then the script fails. Is there anyway of using CONCAT_WS that if there is a NULL CID the script still runs, but without the county title?

Cheers
G

Comment: your query looks fine, you can add all needed fields to concat_ws. IF you get no results it's because you have one after the filters are applied. your filters are the inner join condition and the where: " Counties.CID=SP_Cont.CID and SP_Cont.SPCode = 26"

Comment: @AdrianBR You are right. I have just used an SPCode that I know has a CID code and it displayed 1 result. The issue, as is clear here, if there is no CID code the script fails to produce any result. Is there a way to concat_ws all the fields I mention above even if the CID code is empty/NULL? Cheers for your comment.

Comment: if you have no CID code, you cannot join on your county table. You can change the join to a left join, so the results from your SP_CONT table will be posted regardless. Also, ifnull, not nullif

Comment: @AdrianBR Yes that works :) I don't suppose you know if you can do an inner join within the CONCAT_WS so that I can format it the way I want it? Cheers

Comment: you can, posted below

Answer (score 0):

nullif works a bit different http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_nullif

```
SELECT 
CONCAT_WS(', ',
  nullif(SP_Cont.Address1, ''),
  nullif(SP_Cont.Address2, ''),
  nullif(SP_Cont.Address3, ''),
  nullif(SP_Cont.Address4, ''),
  nullif(SP_Cont.Address5, ''),
  nullif(SP_Cont.City, ''),
  nullif(Counties.CTitle, '')
  nullif(Postcode, '')
) AS Address, 

SP_Cont.CID, SP_Cont.RevTot


FROM  SP_Cont
LEFT JOIN Counties
ON Counties.CID=SP_Cont.CID

WHERE SP_Cont.SPCode = "26"
```

Comment: This simply produces something like this "Loughborough Sports Club, Moor Lane, , , , Loughborough, , LE11 1ST". Additional commas where there shouldn't be. NULLIF removes the unwanted commas "Loughborough Sports Club, Moor Lane, Loughborough, LE11 1ST". Getting the county name into the address string is the issue, hmmmmm

Comment: I guess I need to some how get the CID code first, then get the Counties.CTitle and then run the CONCAT_WS including the CTitle.

Comment: CTitle is the county name, isn't it? it's in there in the query above.

Comment: ALso, you are right with nullif. I knew that concat(string, null) returns null, was unaware that concat_ws(separator,string, null) would not return null

Comment: changed back to nullif